# Filtrar lenguaje de un archivo XML en PHP

Tags: php, xml, xpath

quería saber si es posible eliminar ciertas etiquetas de un XML en PHP.

Necesito los datos solo en castellano (0) y me gustaría obtener los datos en un nuevo XML sin los demás idiomas. No se que tipo de filtrado debería utilizar exactamente. Y ando algo perdido.

Si uso xPatch:

```
//adComments[language="0"]
```

Solo conseguiría filtrar y obtener los comentarios, y necesito además las demás referencias.

La estructura es la siguiente:

```
<ads>
    <comments>
      <adComments>
        <propertyComment>
          Extraordinaria oportunidad.
        </propertyComment>
        <language>0</language>
      </adComments>
      <adComments>
        <propertyComment>
          Extraordinaire opportunité.
        </propertyComment>
        <language>2</language>
      </adComments>
      <adComments>
        <propertyComment>
          Oportunidade de investimento.
        </propertyComment>
        <language>4</language>
        </adComments>
        <adComments>
          <propertyComment>
            Extraordinary investment.
          </propertyComment>
          <language>1</language>
        </adComments>
    </comments>
    <multimedias>
    </multimedias>
    <services>
    </services>
</ads>
```

Actualizo:

He probado así:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$respuestaFTP = 
file_get_contents("xml.url");

$xml = simplexml_load_string($respuestaFTP); 
$items = $xml->xpath("/ads/comments/adComments[language > 0]");
foreach ($items as $i) unset($i[0]);

$convertido = $xml->asXML();

$str = convertido;
echo trim($str, '"');
```

Y consigo lo siguiente:

```
<ads>
    <comments>
      <adComments>
        <propertyComment>
          Extraordinaria oportunidad.
        </propertyComment>
        <language>0</language>
      </adComments>



    </comments>
    <multimedias>
    </multimedias>
    <services>
    </services>
</ads>
```

Solo me quedaría eliminar esos espacios que quedan.

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de como podría hacerlo?

Muchas gracias a todos.

Answer (score -1):

Solucionado. Estos despistes me matan.

```
header('Content-Type: application/xml');
```

Comment: Hola Maso. Me alegra que lo solucionaras pero para que la respuesta sea de calidad has de explicar que diferencias tiene el `json` y `xml` en el header. Añade informacin al respecto para que futuros usuarios puedan entender cuándo usar una u otra. Un saludo!